# Dynamically allocate an array, change and display the values it stores

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am trying to build a rudimendary memory allocator which suppors some functions:

- INITIALIZE (creates a char array with N elements), FINALIZE (frees the memory allocated for the array)
- DUMP (displays all the values stored in the array at that moment)
- ALLOC (assigns a certain number of char elements to the user, so that he can store some values in it)

I encountered a problem with the DUMP and ALLOC functions: DUMP does not print the values stored in the array (it prints instead some garbage values), and I cannot find out how to modify the values stored in the array(needed for ALLOC).

Below I post the source code for my functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void initialize(int N, char **v)
{
    int i;
    *v = (char*)malloc(N * sizeof(char));
    printf("Initialized array with %d char elements \n", N);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        v[i] = 0;
        printf("%hhd ", v[i]);
    }
}

void finalize(char *v)
{
    printf("Memory of the array has been freed \n");
    free(*v);
}

void dump(char **v, int N)
{
    int i;
    printf("Memory map:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%hhd ", v[i]);
    }
}
```

In my main function, I have `char *v`,`int N` and for calling the functions:
`initialize(N, &v)`,
`finalize(&v)` and
`dump(&v,N)`. `N` is the number of elements the array is going to store.

Comment: Use `printf("%p ", (void*)v[i]);` to print pointers.

Comment: `free(*v);` in `finalize()` is wrong because it passes something that might not be valid pointer to `free()`.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. And `sizeof(char)` is useless, as it wil never differ from `1`.

Comment: I used `printf("%p ", (void*)v[i])` in my `dump` function but it seems that it prints nothing.

Comment: `v[i] = 0;` after `*v = (char*)malloc(N * sizeof(char));` will erase the address of the allocated memory and cause memory leak.

Comment: All `v[i]` shown should be `(*v)[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to print the elements stored, you just need to pass a pointer to pointer. Just pass the pointer:

```
char *v;
...
...
finalize(v);
```

and modify `dump()`:

```
void dump(char *v, int N)
{
    int i;
    printf("Memory map:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", v[i]);
    }
}
```

Similarly, you don't need a pointer to pointer for `finalize()` either. You typically need to pass a pointer to pointer if you want to modify the pointer (like in your `initialize()`).

`initialize()` also has a problem. This `v[i]` accessing wrong as you want to modify the pointee, not the pointer itself.

You can modify it:

```
void initialize(int N, char **v)
{
    int i;
    char *t = malloc(N * sizeof(char));

    if (t == NULL) {/* error*/ }

    printf("Initialized array with %d char elements \n", N);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        t[i] = 0;
        printf("%hhd ", t[i]);
    }
    *v = t;
}
```